# How do I create new MySQL Database from inside my Sinatra app in Cloudry Foundry?

Tags: mysql, sinatra, cloud-foundry

I'm practicing building a Sinatra app on Cloud foundry micro. This app is using a MySQL service. I am wondering how can i create a new database from my Sinatra app. The New database will hold information that is different from the default database, which i build with data-mapper

I've first tried to use the mysql2 gem

```
require 'mysql2'
con = Mysql.new("#{hostname}", "#{username}", "#{password}", "#{dbname}")   
      rs = con.query("CREATE DATABASE #{$newDbName}")
con.close
```

the code above worked fine on my developer machine so i thought i would try it on the cloud. here is where I'm having a problem:

```
require 'mysql2'
require 'json'
 svcs = JSON.parse ENV['VCAP_SERVICES']
 mysql = svcs.detect { |k,v| k =~ /^mysql/ }.last.first
 creds = mysql['credentials']
 user, pass, host, name = %w(user password host name).map { |key| creds[key] }

con = Mysql.new("#{host}", "#{user}", "#{pass}", "#{name}") 
      rs = con.query("CREATE DATABASE #{ $newDbName}")
con.close
```

When I push my app and go through the process of creating a new database I get a "Internal Server Error" when my app tries to "load 'dbsync/createdb.rb'"

can anyone explain why i am getting this error? or how i can further troubleshoot this issues

Comment: Why would you create a (separate) database from your application? It's not very common that an application does that.

Comment: for another application I'm experimenting with the concept of managing multiple apps through an online interface(HTML forms)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have permission to create a new database. However, if you really wanted to do this you could potentially use the VMC gem to connect to a vcap / Cloud Foundry instance and create a new MySQL service and then bind it to the same application.

Take a look at the commented example code in the VMC codebase at https://github.com/cloudfoundry/vmc/blob/master/lib/vmc/client.rb

Comment: I should add, if you need any assistance with this, I can help.